# Make instance of a jquery plugin?

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to get a simple plugin I made to reate multiple instances when called. It simply takes two images, puts them one of top of the second and fades them in and out with a timer. I've read several posts about making instances from plugins but nothing seems to be working. Im guessing theres some small thing I'm missing. Right now, it creates 3 instances and the top image fades for all 3, but then only the last one continues the loop:

```
var _top;
var _bottom; 
var images;

;(function( $ ){
    $.fn.pictureFade = function( options ){

        return this.each(function(){

        var $this = $(this);

        //run some code here


        var settings = $.extend({},options);
        images = settings.images;
         topImage = options.top;
         botImage = options.bot;



        i = 0;
        _top = $(topImage+" img");
        _bottom = $(botImage+" img");

        //Set first images
        $(_top).attr("src", images[i]);
        $(_bottom).attr("src", images[i+1]);  


        toggleDiv("top");


        });

    };




})( jQuery );


function toggleDiv(pos){

            if(pos == "top"){

                _top.delay(2000).fadeToggle(4000, "linear", function(){

                    i++;
                    if(i == images.length-1)i = -1;
                    _top.attr("src", images[i+1]);
                    toggleDiv("bottom");    
                }
        );  
        }   

        if(pos == "bottom"){
                 $(_top).delay(2000).fadeToggle(4000, "linear", function(){
                    $(_bottom).attr("src", images[i+1]);  
                     toggleDiv("top");

                }
           );
        }   
}
```

Here's the script to run it. Note fadeImage is a wrapper of topImage and botImage:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     $( document ).ready(function() {


    $("#fadeImage").pictureFade({
        images: [
        "images/aztec5.jpg",
        "images/aztec3.jpg", 
        "images/aztec7.jpg",
        "images/aztecicon.jpg"],

        top: "#topImage",
        bot: "#botImage"
    });

    $("#fadeImage2").pictureFade({
        images: [
        "images/aztec7.jpg",
        "images/aztec6.jpg",
        "images/aztec3.jpg", 
        "images/aztecicon.jpg"],

        top: "#topImage2",
        bot: "#botImage2"
    });

    $("#fadeImage3").pictureFade({
        images: [
        "images/aztec3.jpg", 
        "images/aztec5.jpg",
        "images/aztec7.jpg",
        "images/aztecicon.jpg"],

        top: "#topImage3",
        bot: "#botImage3"
    });

    });


    </script>
```

Comment: You don't really need instances, you just have to stop using the same global variables everytime the plugin is called, move the variables inside the plugin.

Comment: Thanks! I thought it might've been something like that. Would those globals cause trouble even if I was instantiating correctly?

Comment: Yes, the plugin uses the same variables everytime it's called, so the second you're calling it, it overwrites those variables from the first time, and things stop working